# What is a TSA policy OID?

Tags: digital-signature

What is TSA policy OID? Is it a unique identifier of a timestamp server given by a world wide authority? Does that mean that no two servers can have the same oid? Or is it an identifier of the characteristics of the service the server provides? In this context, can a TSA server have more than one OID? I have seen that this Id is a string of numbers, separated by dots hinting that this ID is comprised of different fields. What is the syntax and meaning of these fields?
Does a user of the server has to mention the OID in the request he makes to the server?

Answer (score 3):

*All* ASN.1 OIDs are sequences of numbers separated by periods, and designed to be globally unique; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_identifier . The numbers have meaning as part of the sequence, but not by themselves. It's vaguely like DNS except left-to-right instead of right-to-left, numbers instead of names, and most importantly there is no expectation or suggestion that the things identified are computers of any kind.

A TSA policy is determined by some entity, usually an organization such as a business; it might be the same for multiple servers operated by one entity, and possibly for servers operated by multiple entities if they agree. It certainly isn't intended to identify the *server*; the IPaddress (and usually domainname) always does that, and the certificate probably does, since normally different servers will use different signing keys and thus different certs. In general what a policy means, how it is used, and if/when it is allowed/required depend on whatever system(s) and party(ies) implement it.

If you mean RFC3161, which is probably the most popular but not the only standard for timestamping, it allows (ASN.1 OPTIONAL) one OID in a request and requires one OID in a `TSTInfo` (i.e. the signed body of a successful response). [It says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3161#page-9)

> ... This policy MAY include the
> following types of information (although this list is certainly not
> exhaustive):

> - The conditions under which the time-stamp token may be used.

> - The availability of a time-stamp token log, to allow later
>   verification that a time-stamp token is authentic.

As you can see this is pretty open-ended -- like for X.509/PKIX *certificate* policies.

The ability to specify a desired OID in a request is clearly intended to allow for the possibility that the server (to which that request is sent) supports more than one policy, but that's only a possibility, I don't know how many if any actually do.